# Integrating custom Android kernel builds with SDK

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-source

I'm extending a custom Android kernel fork that originated as a 2.2
Froyo kernel. The build process itself is no problem; just type "make"
and its done. But I'm not sure of what I need to do to make the new 
kernel known to other tools in the Android SDK; particularly
the emulator, adb, and the Eclipse debugger.

I've tried various things such as running the emulator with -system and
-userdata arguments on the command line, and these appear to work,
although I hit sporatic problems that leave me unsure. A common problem
I've seen is that sometimes apps "hang", displaying their UI but
refusing to go away even when the home or menu buttons are clicked. I've
tried turning off caching. But the real problem here is that I don't
have a good mental model of how kernel builds should be conveyed to
the SDK.

Should I be copying the build results (.img files) to
~/.android/ perhaps? Or to somewhere in the
SDK folder?

A working recipe would be nice, but better yet would be a 
understanding of how the kernel build and SDK tools work together.
For example http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html is 
great for recipes but I still don't see how adb and emulator know
where to load .img files from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've built android image the android webpage recommends to run it with `emulator` command. But you can run the built image in this way because android `envsetup` command has specified some paths before. For instance, to test my built image I run command:

```
out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator -sysdir out/target/product/generic/ -system out/target/product/generic/system.img -ramdisk out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img -data out/target/product/generic/userdata.img -kernel prebuilt/android-arm/kernel/kernel-qemu -sdcard sdcard.img -skindir sdk/emulator/skins -skin WVGA800 -scale 0.7 -memory 512 -partition-size 1024
```

So as you can see I specify all the images and all the paths explicitly. This is command to run image in emulator. `Out` folder is created during the build in your android source root folder.

P.S. Kernel usually refers to Linux kernel of Android. In your case, I think you have changed Android framework.

Comment: Yes, the fork I'm using includes the linux kernel and java bits they call "middleware". By kernel, I meant the combination.

Comment: But I still don't see how the new emulator (from your cmd line) gets picked up and used by eclipse and tools like the AVD builder. Do I need to configure something there, or does eclipse pay attention to the environment. I seem to recall running eclipse from a terminal picks this up but running Eclipse.app doesn't. This is all on Mac OSX by the way.

Comment: To build the tools you have to run make sdk command. But how to connect them with eclipse I do not know. You can run them separately from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I've composed a full answer based on the invaluable clues Yury provided. The solution was to add these settings to my .bashrc. The tools (emulator, adb, ddms) in eclipse use these settings to pick up stuff from ANDROID_TARGET_OUT instead of getting them from the prebuilt copies inside the SDK. The CACHE stuff is the standard recommendation.

```
# Android SDK Build settings
export ANDROID_HOME="/Volumes/DroidImg/android-sdk-macosx"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$ANDROID_HOME"
export ANDROID_SDK_BASE="$ANDROID_HOME"
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME="$ANDROID_HOME"
export ANDROID_TARGET_OUT="/Volumes/DroidImg/Droid-Kernel/out/target/product/generic"
export USE_CCACHE=1
export CCACHE_DIR="/Volumes/DroidImg/CCACHE_DIR"
ulimit -S -n 1024
```

Finally, copy the .classpath provided with the SDK as documented on the wiki into the root of the kernel distribution, and "import existing files" into Eclipse. All Java components should now open and build properly in the package explorer. Very handy for exploring but don't forget you have to use ordinary make to build this stuff for real.

/Volumes/DroidImg is a case-preserving disk image I made for MAC-OS work; change this part of the path to suit.